# how know if uitableview has a selected cell

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview

I'm developing an App and at some point I have several uitableview.
I want to know outside the delegate methods, an action for instance, if the tableviews have a selected cell and which one.

I tried to use: `(NSIndexPath *)indexPathForSelectedRow` but it doesn't work, because if I don't have a selected cell the `[(NSIndexPath *) row]` returns "0" and not nil

could you please give any help??

thanks..

Comment: You could save the index of the selected row in an ivar.

Comment: Yes, that's an idea. I already have a NSMUtablearray that stores the selected cell.
As I cannot replace a nil object in NSMUtablearray, I can't initiate the "i" index to nil.

So the problem is to know if a determinated tableview has a selected cell.
made myself clear?
thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your method is correct - indexPathForSelectedRow indeed returns nil if no cell is selected. But if you try to send message to nil object and use the value returned it will be 0, so you need to test if path value is nil or not before trying to get cell's row from it:

```
NSIndexPath *path = [table indexPathForSelectedRow];
if (path){
   row = [path row];
   ...
}
else{
 // No cell selected
}
```

P.S. nil is just a typecasted 0, so in practise they are the same thing.